# Scala/Gatling: How do I append to an array within a foreach?

Tags: scala, foreach, gatling

I'm uber new with Scala/Gatling, so I apologize in advance if this question is dumb.

Writing gatling tests, and I've got a foreach that iterates through a list of items, makes a request to a URL, and verifies the response.

Now, I'd like to take an element from each response and create an array of them in the session for future use.

Here's some code:

```
 foreach("collection","currentItem"){
       exec(
         http(requestName)
         .post([redacted])
         .param([redacted])
         .check(
           regex(""""error":\s*"([^"]*)"""").find.notExists
         )
         .check(
           regex(""""id":\s*"([^"]*)"""").findAll.saveAs([HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCK])
         )
       )
     }
```

I don't want to just use saveAs("someString"), or it'll be overwritten with every iteration of the foreach.  What I need is all of the ids from each response to be appended to an array that I can then throw into the session.

I've been googling all morning, but every other search takes me to a github page that says "the documentation has been moved", and then provides a link to nowhere.  I also didn't see any relevant stackoverflow posts.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly in the check. You have to add an extra [exec](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/general/scenario.html#exec) step after your request, but inside the loop that would fetch from the [Session](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/session/session_api.html#id2) the previously stored accumulator and what was saved by the check in the current iteration, and push the result back into the Session.

Comment: Beautiful.  That makes perfect sense.  Thanks!